# Quotient spaces and annihilators of inifinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, modules, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ be the dual space of $V$. For a subspace  $U$ of $V$, we define
$$
U^0 = \{f\in W \mid f(u)=0 \text{ for all } u\in U \}.
$$

We are looking for an example in which
$$
 U_1^0 + U_2^0 \subset (U_1 \cap U_2)^0
$$
but not equal. We could prove the equality when $\dim(V)$ is finite. Thus, we are looking for an example for infinite case.

Comment: I think that you may be mixed up. The reverse inclusion always holds, regardless of dimension. *Proof.* Let $f_1 + f_2 \in U_1^0 + U_2^0$ with $f_i \in U_i^0$ for $i=1,2$. By definition,$f_i(u_i) = 0$ for any $u_i \in U_i$. Now consider $u \in U_1 \cap U_2$. Clearly, $(f_1 + f_2)(u) = f_1(u) + f_2(u) = 0 + 0 = 0$; hence, $f_1 + f_2 \in (U_1 \cap U_2)^0$.

Comment: The statement $(U_1 + U_2)^0 \subseteq U_1^0 + U_2^0$ also holds in infinite dimensions, provided that we're talking about purely algebraic vector spaces, where only finite sums make sense. [Here's a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3828886/6509).

Comment: Since you tagged this with `functional-analysis` and `hilbert-spaces` you might be interested in *normed* vector spaces (so we can make sense of infinite sums, convergence, and bring in topology). In this context, it's typical to work with *continuous* duals, in which case [here's a counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3852312/6509) showing that $(U_1 + U_2)^0 \nsubseteq U_1^0 + U_2^0$.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I have fixed it.